# Matplotlib: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension Error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([1.628,1.548,1,451,1.386,1.280])
y = np.array([0.124,0.086,0.045,0.013,-0.032])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show();
```

Hi,

I know this has been asked before. I have tried to convert the lists into numpy arrays but unfortunately the same error occurs. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Change 1,451 to 1.451 in x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a spurious comma in your x definition: `1,451` instead of `1.451`.